# Pass Data and redirect to a new page in .net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html, httpwebrequest

I looking ways to redirect the page from the server side code and pass couple variables into the new page ( i can pass the same data through query string or session but i dont want to do that)   what is the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: "post couple variables..." like HTTP POST? Than you can't do that since POST had to be triggered from browser side. You can render HTML page that will self-post on load, but it does not satisfy your requirement of server side redirect.

Comment: It Just figured out that thank you i am editing it   form Post  to pass ...   what would be the better way for doing above

Answer (score 7):

You have a few options:

- QueryStrings (you don't want to use this)
- ASP.Net Session (you don't want to use this)
- Multiple hidden forms with variables (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/magazine/cc164151.aspx)
- Using the Button PostBackUrl attribute.
- Expose page properties/variables as public - dirty.
- ASP.Net Cache
- NCache (http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/)
- Server.TransferRequest (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa344901.aspx)
  . Can handle any additional headers you place inside the request (post data).